# url not found when extending the default app engine url

Tags: google-app-engine

goolge engine app with default url - http://6.version.myapp.appspot.com/ works, but http://6.version.myapp.appspot.com/test gives me a :

404 Not Found.

The resource could not be found.

my app.yaml file is as follows :

```
application: myapp
version: 6
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /test
  script: pythonfile.py

- url: /.*
  script: pythonfile.
```

testing locally works fine : localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/test - both work fine.

Above the number 6 just happens to be a version no. So I am guessing for any other number the problem will happen. If I make the 6th version the default and access the url without version no, it works fine with and without the '/test' extension on the default url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"6.version.yourapp.appspot.com" is not accessing version "6" of your app, it's accessing the version called "version". Thanks to wildcard subdomains, if that version doesn't exist, the request goes to your primary version.

I suspect you're thinking of the old version naming scheme, under which version 6 would be "6.latest.yourapp.appspot.com"; now it's simply "6.yourapp.appspot.com".

Comment: Understand it better now. Thanks.

Comment: Nick, this worked very well and many thanks for your help. I have another problem where http POST calls are getting redirected by the app-server into a GET call and then my handler is called. when I use it on localhost:8080 thru the app-engine launcher program, it POSTs are being called properly. It is only after I deploy and call it thru app-server on the app-engine.. (I have posted another question with the log from the app-engine : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305691/google-app-engine-converting-redirecting-http-post-to-get-calls-into-the-handl)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your handler should look like that if you've got python 2.7? I think it should be eg handler.app instead of handler.py and if you follow the guestbook example from the SdK it probably does exactly what you are trying to do. You can also read Nick Johnson's blog post from blog.notdot.net how to upgrade to python 27 the official way - I don't think you put the script names in your app.yaml, I think it's supposed to look like
`pythonfile.app`
or
`pythonfile.application`
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found is from errors in app.yaml file, not your python coding. Look into the 'logs' of your appengine console and you'd find more information relating to this error. A good place to start is with GAE's [Python 2.7](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) introduction page since it is too long to list here.

Changes aren't numerous though it can easily break your app if u miss a step (as it did to mine).