# google app engine converting (redirecting) HTTP POST to GET calls into the Handler

Tags: google-app-engine

Https POST's on google app engine are getting redirected to app url with a GET and losing all arguments.

> 2011-11-28 22:21:06.026 / 302 218ms 0kb
>   71.167.39.92 - - [28/Nov/2011:19:21:06 -0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4" -
>   "9.appname.appspot.com" ms=219 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000095

My handler is not called at this time, and app engine redirects above post to

> 2011-11-28 22:21:06.100 / 200 13ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
>   71.167.39.92 - - [28/Nov/2011:19:21:06 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1661 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/6.0.2" "9.appname.appspot.com" ms=14 cpu_ms=23 api_cpu_ms=0
>   cpm_usd=0.000873 instance=00c61b117c6840ba7ad8c376b950491ada80

This happens for every post. A HTTPs GET calls my handler directly.

Comment: What is the redirect destination?

Answer (score 2):

I had a `secure=always` on my `app.yaml` - which caused the redirects to trigger every time on POSTs and resulted in GET's with full loss of post parameters (like `signed_requests` for FB apps for example). It is solved now.